# How to use Ext.resizer.Resizer in a Ext.window.Window for xtype: image

Tags: image, resize, resizable

The examples given in the API docs for ExtJS 4.0.7 for "Resizable" prove that I can accomplish what I'm trying to do. As with most of the examples, however, none are provided using MVC. Attempting to figure out how to use the examples has been quite a challenge. In this case, I'm stumped.

I have an app that will display an image in a window and it works. I need to be able to allow the user to resize the window and have the image inside resize with it. It appears this is very doable. I just can't figure it out.

My controller code is as follows:

```
onDoubleClickPage: function(view, rec, item, index, e, eopts) {
    var image = rec.get('PGPATH');
    if (image === '') {
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: 'View Document',
            msg: 'No Document on file',
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
            icon: Ext.Msg.INFO
        });
        return;
    }

    var showImage = new Ext.window.Window({
        height: 600,
        width: 500,
        title: 'View Book Page',
        closeAction: 'destroy',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'image',
                height: 500,
                width: 400,
                autoScroll: true,
                resizable: true,
                src: image
            }
        }]
    }).show();
}
```

The above code works, but as you can imagine, I get a fixed sized image. My window resizes, but the image, of course, does not.

I've tried a plethora of things to try and invoke and/or configure the resizer, but, alas, nothing has worked. I'm clueless at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

set layout: 'fit' in the Window then use Ext.Img to create the image http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Img